# Connect a server through another server in putty/jump server using java

Tags: java, sftp, putty, scp, winscp

I need to connect to another server after i logged into putty server using java code and I need to download files from second server after I connected. Do anyone have the code.

Once the putty server screen appears, I enter username and password then i pass the command "ssh servername" then i need to enter yes for the question appears.

Once the above done, I have to navigate to different folders and download the files to Server1.

I used the below code to connect to server1 and it connected, After that I am not sure of jumping to server 2.

I am getting the error as below when i am trying a remote server through another server. The error and code I have entered below

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:236)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
        at putty.putty.main(putty.java:42)
```

Code I used:

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class putty {
    public static String user = "username";
    public static String host = "server1.server.net";
    public static String password = "Password";
    public static String secondpassword = "Password";
    public static String tunnelRemoteHost = "server2.server.net";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSchException, SftpException {
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();    
        int port = 22;    
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();

        int forwardPort = 2222;
        session.setPortForwardingL(forwardPort, tunnelRemoteHost, 22);
        Session secondSession = jsch.getSession(user, "localhost", forwardPort);
        secondSession.setPassword(secondpassword);
        secondSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");        
        secondSession.connect();      
        session.openChannel("sftp");
         // now we're connected to the secondary system
        Channel channel = secondSession.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;     

        channel.disconnect();

        session.disconnect();

        System.out.print(outputBuffer.toString());

    }
}
```

I am using latest jsch jar 0.1.55. Can someone look into and let me what I am missing here.

Comment: can you specify version of **jsch** ?

Comment: Version is 0.1.42

Comment: Version is 0.1.42. After I connected Server 1 and enter the command "SSH Server2" to connect 2nd server.

Comment: I entered "Putty" as a reference . Usually, I will connect putty manually to connect to the server. So I marked the reference. My code doesn't refer anything with Putty.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  he is doing all the same

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I have updated the jar version to 0.1.55. Is the code correct?

Comment: So edit your question to say that you are using the latest version and it still does not work.

Comment: Can you connect using port forwarding with PuTTY? -- You can also try native tunneling functionality of WinSCP: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Nope, its not working if i try portForwarding in Putty or native tunneling with Winscp

Comment: OK, then you should talk to your server administrator.

Comment: You can of course *hack* it by executing `ssh` on the `session`. But that's not a nice way.

Comment: I am able to do it all through manual commands. but i failed through java code

Comment: Sure. But that's not port forwarding. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update **jsch** to 0.1.55 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.55

Your current version 0.1.42 is almost 10 years old. It may not change anything or may help.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve what i wanted through Windows Commandline with plink command